# Is it possible to create a sort of template/zone to guide others where to insert images in a Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have to create a Word document that will be used as a template for reports, each report will need to have people insert images(screenshots) into their documents.

Is it possible to specially mark a zone, like a big square or something "this is where you need to insert your screenshot"?

Or maybe mark the borders of the screenshot and they just click and they can add into it a screenshot or other image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes, you can use a Picture Content Control

This is on the [Developer Tab](http://addbalance.com/word/developertab.htm).

*(This is in the Windows desktop version of Word. It can be done [on the Mac](https://www.brandwares.com/bestpractices/2019/08/content-controls-for-macos-cool-code/) but is harder.) One way to do it on the Mac is to use a document developed in Word for Windows that has the control and copy that control into your template. Here is a [link to such a document on my website](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#ContentControlsMac).)*

[image: screenshot of ribbon control]

[image: screenshot of control]

Clicking on this gives the user this set of choices for the source.

[image: screenshot of dialog]

When the picture is inserted, it will be the size of your control. It can be resized, though, like any picture.

[image: screenshot after insertion]

When it is not selected, the control tab and bounding box are invisible.

[image: screenshot]

### You can save this in a [custom Document Template](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm) for reuse or as a [Building Block](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/autotextautocorrect.htm).

Comment: Thank you actually I need this on Mac I'll try your link and hopefully get back to mark this as the correct answer as soon as possible.

Comment: The easiest way to do this for use on a Mac is to get hold of a Windows computer and create the template there. The template can be used on a Mac. Otherwise it *can* be done on a Mac using vba as demonstrated by Paul Korchok on his page. Once you have such a control, save it as AutoText for future use as well as putting it in your document template. You can even save it as AutoText in that template if that is the only place it will be used. Here is a document with Basic Content Controls. http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#ContentControlsMac Copy from there into your template and AutoText.

Comment: Thank you it worked, by any chance do you know if it's possible to have "Take a screenshot" among the options for when you click and it asks you what image to use ? Not required but I thought since you knew exactly what to do, maybe it's possible. Answer marked as the correct solution in any case.

Comment: It is possible to have the "title" that shown on the control say "Insert a Screenshot" instead of "Picture" but I do not know that this helps. This is done in the properties of the control. Again, easily edited in Windows; not easy on the Mac. I suspect that you would want people to save the screenshot as a file and import it. You can select the control and paste into it. You can also paste a picture into a rich-text content control but can't size it in advance.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.